# Precision difference between \pgfmathsetmacro and \pgfplotsretval

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, pgfmath

I am currently working on some datasets with `pgfplots` and `pgfplotstable`.

At some point, I need to store some cell values for mutiple uses so I use a `\pgfmathsetmacro{\somevar}{\pgfplotsretval}` call.
However, there are some precision issues between the two values.

Can anyone clarify this issue ?

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{testfile.csv}
A, B
1, 0.19959E-002
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{testfile.csv}{\testdata}

\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{B}\of\testdata
\pgfmathsetmacro{\valueinB}{\pgfplotsretval}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\testdata}};
    \node at (0,-1cm) {Value of pgfplotsretval \pgfplotsretval};
    \node at (0,-1.5cm) {Value of pgfmathsetmacro \valueinB};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is the difference between using `fpu` (see section **56 Floating Point Unit Library** of the pgfmanual v. 3.1.3) and not using it.

Comment: @marmot, you are right, as often :). Feel free to post an answer if you want. I was a bit reluctant to use `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}` because it leads to errors in my code. Is there a way to use it in options for `\pgfmathsetmacro` or maybe with a group ? Just to ensure it is set only locally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the difference between using `fpu` and not using it. As for your question to locally use it: there are several ways, but things become more convenient recently after `\pgfmathsmuggle` was added to `pgf`. (If you cannot compile the following, chances are you have an older version of pgf. I also think that the errors you were mentioning in your comment will go away if you use `fixed`, i.e. `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}` instead of just `\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true}`.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm,10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
%\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{testfile.csv}
A, B
1, 0.19959E-002
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{testfile.csv}{\testdata}

\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{B}\of\testdata
\begingroup\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=true,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\valueinB}{\pgfplotsretval}%
\pgfmathsmuggle\valueinB%
\endgroup

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (a) at (0,0) {\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type]{\testdata}};
    \node at (0,-1cm) {Value of pgfplotsretval \pgfplotsretval};
    \node at (0,-1.5cm) {Value of pgfmathsetmacro \valueinB};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]